# Do for loops using range(len(arr)-1,-1,-1), arr[::-1] and reversed(arr) have the same time complexity?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, for-loop

I am studying the coding interview and I am not sure if I should use:

```
for i in range(len(arr)-1,-1,-1):
    print(arr(i))
```

because it is clearly O(n)?

Are slicing and reversed increase the time complexity to O(n^2)?

```
for n in arr[::-1]:
    print(n)


for n in reversed(arr):
    pring(n)
```

Comment: Why would the other methods be O(N^2)?

Comment: it reverses it only once so you have only `O(N+N)` which means `O(N)`

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanations. I misunderstood. It is O(n) @roganjosh